# Magento - Uncaught ReferenceError: billing is not defined

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, billing

Upon hitting continue on the shipping method step, it won't allow me to proceed further to "Billing" step. I have previously rearranged this order so that the order is shipping->shippingmethod->billing information->payment information->order review but this issue had occurred before too (would not proceed beyond billing step).

I have looked around and can't seem to fix this issue that I am having on my Magento website. This is the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: billing is not defined(anonymous function) @ (index):638

When I click into the javascript source error, this is highlighted:

```
billing.onSave = function(evt){
    new Ajax.Updater('onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load', 'http://dev.vaughanflowers.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/getAdditional/', {onSuccess: function() {
          this.nextStep(evt);
    }.bind(this), evalScripts:true});
}.bindAsEventListener(billing);
```

I have compared and ensure that the billing in my core files are consistent with the billing.phtml in my theme persistent folder but that is all. I have seen very little articles on this error and in my case, the theme does not provide this file so I am assuming it's calling the core template file instead:

> app\design\frontend\base\ {interface} \ {theme} \template\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml

This is the URL of the checkout (Hope this helps): http://dev.vaughanflowers.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/